# locales (UTF-8) are not set as expected

Tags: apache2, php, locale, filename, utf-8

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS is installed on my virtual machine. When I use PuTTY to login, I get the following output:

```
  karsten@v38xxx:~$ who am i
  karsten  pts/0        Jun 26 10:14 (87.175.23.xx)
  karsten@v38xxx:~$ locale
  LANG=
  LANGUAGE=
  LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
  LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
  LC_TIME="POSIX"
  LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
  LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
  LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
  LC_PAPER="POSIX"
  LC_NAME="POSIX"
  LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
  LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
  LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
  LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
  LC_ALL=
  karsten@v38xxx:
```

With these settings I am not able to open some files like *strandcafé.inc*. When I changed my identity to the **same** user:

```
  karsten@v38xxx:~$ su karsten
  Password:
  karsten@v38xxx:~$ who am i
  karsten  pts/0        2020-06-26 10:14 (87.175.23.xx)
  karsten@v38xxx:~$ locale
  LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
  LANGUAGE=
  LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
  LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
  karsten@v38xxx:~$
```

You can see I havn't really changed my identity - login name has not been changed. But the locales are changed. Why? Or where does the locales come from?
Here my settings:
/etc/default/locale:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

and /etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

I am facing some other problems on my webserver (apache). The PHP script is not able to load some files with UTF-8 characters in the filename. I assume the problem above is related to this.
Any hints are appreciated.